# How to install Fogger?

Tags: installation, package-management

I Want to know that how to install Fogger application, which Interact with different web accounts including Facebook on Ubuntu 13.10.

In main Ubuntu repository, it is only available for Ubuntu 12.10

How to install it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fogger** can be installed with [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/+search?field.text=desktop-facebook+ppa&field.actions.search=Search) repository **ppa:loneowais/fogger**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:loneowais/fogger

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install fogger
```