# How do I install fogger?

Tags: software-installation

when I try to install foggger with these instructions it doesn't work:[How to install Fogger?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380533/how-to-install-fogger). Terminal says it can't find the package. What do I do?

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt-get update`? Also, are you using Ubuntu 14.04? What I'm guessing is your issue is that the latest released package from that PPA is for 13.10. If you look [here](https://launchpad.net/~loneowais/+archive/fogger) you can see this by looking at the most recent published package.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness Ya im running 14.04. Can I force install it even though I have 14.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the software the OP wants to install has only been built for the previous version of Ubuntu, 13.10, while the OP is running 14.04.

So, you'll have to edit the software entry via **Modify** within **Software & Updates** on the **Other Software** tab. Click on the **Other Software** tab, select the PPA you want to edit, and press <kbd>Edit</kbd> at the base of the window, next to the <kbd>Add</kbd> button.

[image: software & updates]

Simply modify the value of **Distribution** (currently `trusty`) to match the version that the software you want to install is built for. In this case, you would change it to saucy, 13.10's codename and the latest version built.